# Consider a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu$).

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Prove that if $\lambda$ is a measure on $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\lambda(B) \geq \mu(B)$, for all $B \in \mathcal{M}$, then there exists a measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal{M}$, such that $\lambda = \mu + \nu$.

Define $\nu$ such that for all $B \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\lambda(B) = \infty$ we have $\nu(B) = \infty$, and for all $B \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\lambda(B) < \infty$ we have $\nu(B) = \lambda(B) - \mu(B)$. Clearly for all $B \in \mathcal{M}$ we have $\lambda(B)  = \mu(B) + \nu(B)$. So it suffice to show $\nu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{M}$. Since for all $B \in \mathcal{M}$ we have $\lambda(B) \geq \nu(B)$, it follows that $\nu(B) = \lambda(B) - \mu(B) \geq 0$. Since $\lambda(\emptyset) = 0 < \infty$ it follows that $\nu(\emptyset) = \lambda(\emptyset) - \mu(\emptyset) = \lambda(\emptyset) - 0 = \lambda(\emptyset) = 0$ where the second equality holds from the fact that $\mu$ is a measure and the fourth equality holds from the fact that $\lambda$ is a measure. Now consider an arbitrary countable collection of disjoint set $\{E_j\}_{j = 1}^\infty \in \mathcal{M}$ such that  $\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j \in \mathcal{M}$. Suppose $\lambda(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j) < \infty$, it follows that $\nu(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j) = \lambda(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j) - \mu(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \lambda(E_j ) - \mu(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j)= \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \lambda(E_j) - \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \mu(E_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty (\lambda(E_j) - \mu(E_j)) = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \nu(E_j)$

were the second equality holds from the fact that $\lambda$ is a measure on $\mathcal{M}$ and the third equality holds from the fact that $\nu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{M}$.

MY PROBLEM: I don't know how to prove if $\lambda(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j) = \infty$ then $\nu(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \nu(E_j)$.

I think in the case where one of the $\lambda(E_i) = \infty$ it suffices to say $\nu(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j) = \lambda(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty E_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \lambda(E_j) = \infty = \nu(E_i) = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \nu(E_j)$. But I don't know how to go about proving if $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty \lambda(E_j) = \infty$ that $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty
 \lambda(E_j) - \mu(E_j) = \infty$ as well?

Comment: It seems that there is a small problem with this definition of $\nu$ for $\sigma$-additivity. Suppose that $E_j$ are disjoint and such that $\lambda(E_j)=j^{-1}+j^{-2}$ and $\mu(E_j)=j^{-1}$. Then $\lambda\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j\right)=+\infty$ hence $\nu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j\right)$. However, $\nu(E_j)=j^{-2}$.

Or I missed something?

Comment: By the way, welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: Thanks Davide Giraudo. It looks like you are right and there is a problem with how I defined $\nu$ when $\lambda$ is infinite. Since $\lambda = \mu +  \nu$, it must be the case that if $\lambda = \infty$ and $\mu < \infty$, that $\nu = \infty$, so I'm going try to change the definition $\nu$ to be $0$ if both $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are infinite. Will comment back weather or not this works.

Comment: Now that I thought about it my second idea wont work ether, since it dosn't hold for the example you gave.

Comment: I had this idea as well and you are right. I will think about it.

Comment: If the measure space is $\sigma$-finite and $X_n\uparrow X$ have finite measure, let $\nu(A)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\lambda(A\cap X_n)-\mu(A\cap X_n)$. Then $\nu(\emptyset)=0$, $\nu$ is sub-additive and if $A_j$ are disjoint, $\nu(\bigcup_j A_j)\geq \nu(\bigcup_{j=1}^JA_j)=\lim_n \sum_{j=1}^J\nu(A_j\cap X_n)=\sum_{j=1}^J\nu(A_j)$ showing the other direction. But I have no idea at the moment for the general case.

Comment: Oh, but this may not work, since if $\mu(A)$ is infinite, the limit defining $\nu$ may not exists.

Comment: Ended up emailing a Professor who told me to define $\nu(B) =$ sup$\{\lambda(E) - \mu(E) : E$ is measurable, $E \subseteq B$, and $\mu(E) < \infty\}$.

Comment: Was able to use this new definition to prove $\lambda(B)  = \mu(B) + \nu(B)$, and $\nu(\emptyset) = 0$ without much difficulty. Also was able to prove that If $\{B_j\}$ is disjoint and $\mu(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty < \infty$ then $\nu(\cup_{j = 1}^\infty) = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \nu(E_j)$.

Comment: Nice! Maybe you can post this as an answer.

Comment: So all that remains is to prove that If $\{B_j\}$ is disjoint and $\mu(\cup_{j =1}^\infty = \infty$ then $\nu(\cup_{j =1}^\infty) = \sum_{j =1}^\infty \nu(E_j)$. I was able to show  $\nu(\cup_{j =1}^\infty) \leq \sum_{j =1}^\infty \nu(E_j)$. Since $\nu(\cup_{j =1} B_j) =$ Sup $\{\lambda(E) -\mu(E) :E \subset \cup_{j =1} B_j, E \in M$ and $\mu(E) < \infty\} =$ Sup $\{\lambda(\cup_{j =1} (E\cap B_j)) -\mu(\cup_{j =1} (E\cap B_j)): "\} =$ Sup $\{\sum_{j =1} \lambda(E\cap B_j) -\mu(E\cap B_j): "\} \leq \sum_{j =1} $ Sup $\{\lambda(E\cap B_j) -\mu(E\cap B_j): "\} = \sum_{j =1} \nu(B_j)$

Comment: For the other inequality, we can assume that $\nu(B_j)$ is finite for all $j$ (otherwise, by monotonicity of $\nu$, both terms are infinite). Fix a positive $\varepsilon$; for all $j$, pick $E_j\in\mathcal M$ such that $\mu(E_j)$ is finite and $\lambda(E_j)-\mu(E_j)>\nu(E_j)-\varepsilon 2^{-j}$. Since for all $J$, $\bigcup_{j=1}^JA_j$ has a finite $\mu$-measure and is contained in $\bigcup_{j\geq 1}B_j$, we derive that $$ \nu(\bigcup_{j\geq 1}B_j)\geq  \nu(\bigcup_{j=1}^ĴB_j)>\sum_{j=1}^J\nu(B_j)-\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

If we let $\nu(B)=\infty$ when $\lambda(B)=\infty$ and $\nu(B)=\lambda(B)-\mu(B)$ if $\lambda(B)<\infty$, then we run into a problem for $\sigma$-additivity, for example if $(B_n)$ is a sequence of disjoint sets such that $\lambda(B_n)=n^{-1}+n^{-2}$ and $\mu(B_n)=n^{-1}$, then $B:=\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}B_n$ has an infinite $\lambda$-measure hence $\nu(B)$ is infinite but $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\nu(B_n)$ is finite. Letting  $\nu(B)=0$ when $\lambda(B)=\infty$ does not work for the same reason.

Instead, it was suggested in the comments to define 
$$
\nu(B):=\sup\left\{\lambda(A)-\mu(A), A\in\mathcal M, A\subseteq B, \mu(A)<+\infty\right\}.
$$
We have to check that $\nu$ does the job.

- $\nu(\emptyset)=0$ since the only subset of $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$ and 
  $\lambda(\emptyset)-\mu(\emptyset)=0$.
- Also, we observe that if $B\subset B'$, then $\nu(B)\leqslant \nu(B')$ because 
  every subset of $B$ is also a subset of $B'$.
- We have to check the equality $\lambda(B)=\mu(B)+\nu(B)$. If $\mu(B)$ is infinite, this is trivial since $\lambda(B)$ is also infinite. If $\mu(B)$ is finite, then $\nu(B)=\mu(B)$ hence the equality hold.
- It remains to check the $\sigma$-additivity. Let $\left(B_j\right)_{j\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint elements of $\mathcal M$. First we prove the sub-additivity. Let $B:=\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}B_n$. Then 
  $$
  \nu(B)=\sup\left\{\sum_{j\geqslant 1}\lambda(A\cap B_j)-\mu(A\cap B_j), A\in\mathcal M, A\subseteq B, \mu(A)<+\infty\right\}\\\leqslant 
  \sum_{j\geqslant 1}\sup\left\{\lambda(A\cap B_j)-\mu(A\cap B_j), A\in\mathcal M, A\subseteq B, \mu(A)<+\infty\right\}
  $$ 
  and if $A\in\mathcal M$ is such that $A\subseteq B$, then $A\cap B_j\subset B_j$ and has finite $\mu$-measure hence 
  $$
  \sup\left\{\lambda(A\cap B_j)-\mu(A\cap B_j), A\in\mathcal M, A\subseteq B, \mu(A)<+\infty\right\}\leqslant \nu(B_j),
  $$
  which proves that $\nu\left(\bigcup_{j\geqslant 1}B_j\right)\leqslant \sum_{j\geqslant 1}\nu(B_j)$.

For the other direction, in view of the second bullet, we can assume that $\nu(B_j)$ is finite for all $j$. Let $\varepsilon$ be fixed. By definition of $\nu$, we can find $A_j\in\mathcal M$ such that $\mu(A_j)$ is finite and 
$\lambda(A_j)-\mu(A_j)>\nu(B_j)-\varepsilon 2^{-j}$. Let us fix $J\geqslant 1$ (we have to truncate the union because we are not sure that $\bigcup_{j\geqslant 1}\mu(A_j)$ is finite). Using again the second bullet, we derive that 
$$
\nu\left(\bigcup_{j\geqslant 1}B_j\right)\geqslant\nu\left(\bigcup_{j= 1}^JB_j\right).
$$
Now, $\bigcup_{j=1}^J A_j$ belongs to $\mathcal M$, its $\mu$-measure is finite and is contained in  $\bigcup_{j= 1}^JB_j$ hence 
$$
\lambda\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^J A_j\right)-\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^J A_j\right)
\leqslant \nu\left(\bigcup_{j= 1}^JB_j\right).
$$
Since $A_j\subset B_j$ and the $B_j$ are disjoint, we derive that 
$$
\nu\left(\bigcup_{j= 1}^JB_j\right)\geqslant \sum_{j=1}^J\lambda(A_j)-\mu(A_j)
\geqslant\sum_{j=1}^J\nu(B_j)-\varepsilon.
$$
We got in total that for all $J\geqslant 1$ and all $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\nu\left(\bigcup_{j\geqslant 1}B_j\right)\geqslant\sum_{j=1}^J\nu(B_j)-\varepsilon
$$
hence we can conclude.